# Adding new select form with options from database

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql

I have been trying to dynamically add a new dropdown list form using javascript. I have no idea how I should proceed with it. What I have rightnow is a html form page with a javascript that allows me to add a new row of text input form. [html Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfiUJ.png)

Here is my current code for this page.

```html
<?php
include('session.php');
?>

<?php 
$ItemID = "ItemID";
$ItemName = "ItemName";
$UnitPrice = "UnitPrice";

$sql = "SELECT ItemID,ItemName,UnitPrice FROM Item";
$result = $db->query($sql);
$sql2 ="SELECT BranchID,BranchLocation FROM Branch";
$result2 = $db->query($sql2);
$sql4 ="SELECT MemberID FROM Membership";
$result4 = $db->query($sql4);

?> 
<html>
<head>
    <title>Add Sales</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="text-center">
        <h1>Add new Sales Record</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <a href="sales.php"><button  class="w3-button w3-black w3-round-large">Back</button></a>
    </div>
    <div class="container" align="right">
        <table class="table-sm">
            <tbody>
                <tr class="table-primar">
                    <th scope="col" style="padding-right: 50px;">ItemID</th>
                    <th scope="col" style="padding-right: 50px">ItemName</th>
                    <th scope="col">UnitPrice</th>
                </tr>

                <?php 
                while($rows = $result->fetch_assoc()) { 
                    ?>
                    <tr class="contents">
                        <td><?php echo $rows[$ItemID]; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $rows[$ItemName]; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $rows[$UnitPrice]; ?></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php   
                } 
                ?> 
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row clearfix">
            <div class="col-md-12 column">
                <form action="addsales.php" method="post">
                    <table class="">
                        <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                            <thead>
                                <tr >
                                    <th class="text-center">
                                        Branch ID
                                    </th>
                                    <th class="text-center">
                                        MemberID
                                    </th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>

                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <select name="branchid">
                                          <option selected></option>
                                          <?php
                                           
                                            while($rows2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()){
                                                ?>
                                                
                                                <option value="<?php echo $rows2["BranchID"];?>"><?php echo $rows2["BranchLocation"];?></option>
                                                
                                                <?php
                                                
                                            }
                                        
                                        ?>
                                        
                                    </select>
                                    </td>
                                        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $login_session; ?>" name='employeeid' class="form-control"/>
                                    <td>
                                        <select name="memberid">
                                          <option selected></option>
                                          <?php
                                           
                                            while($rows4 = $result4->fetch_assoc()){
                                                ?>
                                                
                                                <option value="<?php echo $rows4["MemberID"];?>"><?php echo $rows4["MemberID"];?></option>
                                                
                                                <?php
                                                
                                            }
                                        
                                        ?>
                                        
                                    </select>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                        <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="tab_logic">
                            <thead>
                                <tr >
                                    <th class="text-center">
                                        ItemID
                                    </th>
                                    <th class="text-center">
                                        Amount
                                    </th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>

                                <tr id='addr0'>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="text" maxlength ="10" name='item[0][itemid]' placeholder='ItemID' class="form-control"/>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="number" name='item[0][amount]' placeholder='Amount' class="form-control"/>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr id='addr1'></tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                        <input class="w3-button w3-black w3-round-large" type="submit" name='submit' value="Submit"/>
                    </form>
                    <button id="add_row" class="w3-button w3-black w3-round-large" style="position: absolute; right: 20px;">New row</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
          $(document).ready(function() {
              var i = 1;
              $("#add_row").click(function() {

                $('#addr' + i).html("<td><input name='item["+i+"][itemid]'  placeholder='ItemID' maxlength='10' class='form-control input-md'/></td><td><input type='text' name='item["+i+"][amount]' placeholder='Amount' class='form-control input-md'/></td>");

                $('#tab_logic').append('<tr id="addr' + (i + 1) + '"></tr>');
                i++;
            });
          });
      </script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

I want to change the javascript code so that instead of adding a new text input form, it will add a select form with options from the database. Something similar to this.

```html
<td>
                                        <select name="memberid">
                                          <option selected></option>
                                          <?php
                                           
                                            while($rows4 = $result4->fetch_assoc()){
                                                ?>
                                                
                                                <option value="<?php echo $rows4["MemberID"];?>"><?php echo $rows4["MemberID"];?></option>
                                                
                                                <?php
                                                
                                            }
                                        
                                        ?>
                                        
                                    </select>
                                    </td>
```

I am really new to all this php and javascript, so my code may look a bit off. Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Since your "select form" depends on MemberID, which is variable, you would likely be suited for an AJAX solution. In the alternative, you could make it so that MemberID would have already been chosen before arriving at this page, and then you'd have the option of building the "select form" without AJAX. There's really *a lot* of different ways to solve your problem.

Comment: Hello @GetSet, thank you for your reply. Can you explain a bit more on the different ways? I have never use AJAX and the like before.

Comment: You're using jQuery, so you could just do this: `$('#some_container').load("somescript.php?memberid=4");` Now all you need is `somescript.php` which grabs `$_GET['memberid']` and echos/prints the HTML you want to insert.